# Intermittent behaviour with delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view I have this link;

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %>
```

which almost always goes to the delete method in the posts controller, as expected. However, very occasionally, I see this type of error in the logs:

```
GET "/posts/1252" for 144.132.171.93 at 2016-07-16 04:57:39 +0000
2016-07-16T04:57:39.885823+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Scheduling item
2016-07-16T04:57:39.885838+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Sending item
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041396+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Got unexpected status code from Rollbar api: 400
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041414+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Response: {
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041416+00:00 app[web.1]:   "err": 1,
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041417+00:00 app[web.1]:   "message": "access token required"
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041418+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2016-07-16T04:57:40.041442+00:00 app[web.1]: [Rollbar] Details: https://rollbar.com/instance/uuid?uuid=ded45ccf-11be-4dfe-af4e-775445b9230e (only available if report was successful)
2016-07-16T04:57:40.042290+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-16T04:57:40.042301+00:00 app[web.1]: AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for PostsController):
```

In the above case, the post with id 1252 does exist. It looks to me that in these cases, the method: :delete is being ignored and instead of deleting the post, it is trying to show the post.  I have tried putting

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

in the head, but this does not work.

I have been able to trigger this on a staging server using a selenium test and when it happens, the confirm script is not triggered.  This suggest to me it is something to do with the page occasionally not loading everything that it needs to interpret this link. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you post the relevant controller code?

Comment: missing remote: true?

Comment: The relevant action is a delete, but I have instrumented it, and the delete method is never reached when this error happens, and the log also shows no sign of it going the delete action.  When the link works correctly, which is most of the time, it does go to the delete action. I should have I added that  been able to trigger this on a staging server using a selenium test and when it happens, the confirm script is not triggered.   What part of the controller are you interested in?

Comment: In answer to Timmy Von Heiss, I have added some more information, which indicates that the confirmation message is not being triggered when this link does not work, so that indicates that the link is being treated as a vanila get:, so I am not sure why the remote: true would change this?  Also I thought remote: true was for an ajax request?